# Can I import my previous songs in Dance Central 2?

Tags: dance-central-2, dance-central

I just got Dance Central 2 and also own Dance Central. Now I'd like to import my Dance Central songs into Dance Central 2, but I have no idea how this works.

I'm also wondering whether the old songs will support the new co-op mode.

**So could someone explain how to import the songs?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, you need to make sure that your copy of Dance Central (note, not DC 2) is first-hand and you will also need Internet connection. On the back of the DC 1 manual that comes with the disc, there should be a redeem code (I will have to confirm that when I get home tonight). This is one time use only (hence the first-hand prerequisite).  If it's second-hand, it's probably not a problem as long as the previous owner hasn't already used the code.

The songs will still cost 400msp on top of the redeem code; however, if you preordered DC 2, you should be able to get it for free through a voucher code (I am not too sure as I didn't preorder mine).

Now load up Dance Central 2. On the main screen, select Options->Redeem code. Enter the code from the first paragraph and confirm the purchase. It will start downloading the Dance Central Import Pack. Hope this helps.

Comment: Great @James, too bad about the 400 MSP requirement though, given that I already bought both games, but ah well... Any idea about the co-op being updated as well?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I'd imagine so. Programmatically, a song simply consists of the music and the moves for the different difficulty levels, so the coop mechanism from DC 2 should work seamlessly with the songs from the original, in theory.